# Run script in remote linux pc and continue execution when closing ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, script

I've a python script that must run forever (it's a websocket data collector that put data into a database). The script sometimes write some output to console.

What I want to do is to execute the script in a remote server that I can reach with `ssh`. When I run the script, I want to close the connection while the script continue to be executed, and from time to time I want to log again in there and check the output of the script.

How can I start the script in the remote server, and checking its output while running every time that I connect to remote server?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `screen`? You can run a command in a screen and connect back to it later. It also lets users share the same screen

Comment: IT seems a god solution, thanks.